# Best way to hardcode filename into EXIF metadata

Tags: metadata

I've got a collection of photos that I need to rename, however I want to keep track of their previous filenames.

Thinking the best way to do this copy the filename into the EXIF header, possibly in the comment field?

Looking for suggestions on the easiest way to do this - tried this with [a few](http://www.velocityreviews.com/forums/showpost.php?p=2320034&postcount=3) of the [EXIF command line tools](http://cpanforum.com/threads/5784), but find EXIF/IPTC a bit confusing and am not sure that it's working correctly - especially since some of these posts are old.

Answer (score 6):

If you happen to use Linux, you can do this by running

```
for filename in *; do jhead -cl "$filename" "$filename"; done
```

in the photo directory. (Presuming you have [jhead](http://www.sentex.net/~mwandel/jhead/).)

In any OS, you just need to find a some Exif command line tool and a way to script the operation. Proper arguments for the tool should be in its documentation. Regarding the script, you'll probably get better answers on [stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/) or [superuser](https://superuser.com/).

Comment: Replace 'for file in *l; do;' with 'foreach filename (*);' if you are using tcsh or csh.